# The information from the form is not sending to the database

Tags: php

It is echoing to the other page but not sending to the database. There is a php page just for to connect to the database.So I took off the connection to the database in this php page but got alot of errors.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    require 'login.php';

        $path = 'img/';
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Grab the image from the POST array
        $fn = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
        $ln = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
        $sex = isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : '';
        $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
        $em = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $pass = isset($_POST['pword']) ? $_POST['pword'] : '';
        $confirm = isset($_POST['cword']) ? $_POST['cword'] : '';

        //$gend = $_POST['gender']; not using now
        $pic = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
        if (!empty($fn) && !empty($ln) && !empty($pic)) {

        // Move the file to the target upload folder
        $target = $path.$pic;//create image source (src)
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target)) {


        // // Connect to the database
        $dbase = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'flowers');
        //Write the data to the database
        $my_query = "insert into members values ('$fn', '$ln', '$sex','$city','$em','$pass', '$pic');"; 
         mysqli_query($dbase, $my_query);


         // Confirm success with the user
         echo '<p>Thank you for registering with us!</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $fn .' '.$ln .'<br />';
         echo '<img src="' . $path . $pic . '" alt="profile image" /></p>';
         echo '<p><a href="index.html">&lt;&lt; Return to home page</a></p>';
        }
        }
        }
```

form code:

```
<div id="formControl">
                <form id="form" action="img_upload.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(); "enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Information</legend>   

                         <label> First Name: </label> <br/>
                            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/> <br/>
                            <span id="f_error"></span><br/><br/>

                        <label>Last Name </label><br/>
                            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/><br/><br/>
                            <span id="l_error"></span><br/>

                        <label> Sex: </label><br/>
                            Male <input type="radio" id="msex" name="sex" value="Male"/>
                            Female <input type="radio" id="fsex" name="sex" value="female"/> <br/> <br/> <br/> 

                        <label>City: </label>
                            <select>    
                                <option value="" selected="selected" name="city" id="add">Select a City</option>
                                <option value="sando">San Fernando</option>
                                <option value="pos">Port of Spain</option>
                                <option value="chag">Chaguanas</option>
                                <option value="arima">Arima</option>
                                <option value="bella">Marabella.</option>
                                <option value="point">Point Fortin</option>
                                <option value="puna">Tunapuna</option>
                                <option value="scarborough">Scarborough</option>

                            </select>
                            <span id="ad_error"></span><br/><br/>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                        <legend>Register</legend>

                        <label>Email Address</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/><br/><br/>
                            <span id="em_error"></span><br/><br/>

                        <label> Password: </label><br/>
                            <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword"/> <br/> <br/>
                            <span id="p_error"></span><br/><br/>

                        <label>Confirm Password: </label><br/>
                            <input type="password" id="cword" name="cword"/> <br/> <br/> 
                            <span id="c_error"></span><br/>

                        <label>Profile Picture: </label><br/>   
                        <input type="file" name="pic" id = "pic" /><br/> <br/> <br/>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>


                    </fieldset>

                </form>

            </div>
```

Comment: Post your form code too!!

Comment: are the DB column correct for the INSERT query ?

Comment: yes the inserts match the database

Comment: Your query is vulnerable for SQL attacks! Use prepared statements instead of putting all values directly to query.

Answer (score 0):

Please check $dbase link after connect to database.
after it check error code.
also you can echo your sql Query to know what sending to database and to valuate that, copy it and execute in direct in your mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the column count of your table matches with the amount of values you are inserting.

I noticed you didn't use the `$gend` variable, yet it may be a column in your table.

Auto-incrementing fields will be set default on +1 each new entry. I tested a similar query and I encountered the following error:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1